# I want to detect circle from after my last line and specify its position

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

#importing image and converting it into float

```
original_image = cv2.imread("C:/Users/Ankit Kumar/Desktop/Project.png")
img=cv2.cvtColor(original_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
vectorized = img.reshape((-1,3))
vectorized = np.float32(vectorized)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
K = 3
attempts=10
ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(vectorized,K,None,criteria,attempts,cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS)
center = np.uint8(center)
res = center[label.flatten()]
result_image = res.reshape((img.shape))
figure_size = 15
plt.figure(figsize=(figure_size,figure_size))
plt.subplot(1,2,1),plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(1,2,2),plt.imshow(res)
plt.title('Segmented Image when K = %i' % K), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

#starting edge detection for the image

```
edges = cv2.Canny(img,150,200)
plt.figure(figsize=(figure_size,figure_size))
plt.subplot(1,2,1),plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(1,2,2),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

#I want to add some lines after this so that it can detect circle in my image and also tells its position according to the plot

Comment: You should specify your language name as a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Hough Circle Tranform at https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html.

```
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,
                           cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,
                           param1=50,
                           param2=30,
                           minRadius=0,
                           maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

for i in circles[0, :]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
```